# MySQL Round 1583

Tags: mysql, rounding

So I'm using an equation and then I'm changing the alias of the code at the very end. How do I round that alias? I tried to use the round function on the whole equation but to no avail I got the error #1583.

Here's the code:

```
select product_name, list_price, discount_percent,
      (.01 * discount_percent) * list_price as ROUND(discount_amount,2),
      list_price - (.01 * discount_percent) * list_price  as net_price
from products;
```

I want the net_price and discount_amount values to be rounded.

Comment: Could you show the version that got the error, not the version that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select product_name, list_price, discount_percent,
      ROUND( (.01 * discount_percent) * list_price, 2 ) as discount_amount,
      ROUND( list_price - (.01 * discount_percent) * list_price, 2 ) as net_price
from products;
```

Comment: You are my life-saver! Thank you!